# How to include and exclude properties in selector using @media with sass

Tags: css, sass, media-queries

I have two SCSSs: for landscape orientation and for portrait.
Part of my portrait SCSS:

```
.img-logo__tree_hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

And part of my landscape SCSS:

```
.img-logo__tree_hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

I tried to refactor these SCSSs into one SCSS and got this:

```
.img-logo__tree_hidden {
  display: none;
  @media all and (orientation: landscape) {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
```

But resulting CSS is:

```
.img-logo__tree_hidden {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

So, what I need to do for resulting this CSS in landscape orientation using @media:

```
.img-logo__tree_hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I have tried your code at sassmeister.com and the output is not like what you've given here. It is as per expectation.

Comment: Me too, the same as @Harry at sassmeister.com it works like a charm

Comment: @Harry is right I guess the real problem you still have the `none` been applied since it's the general style so even if the condition of the media is true the element is still `none`

Answer (score 0):

I've won this trouble. In sassmeister everything's alright. But in my SCSS not alright.
I've just add another @media:

```
@media all and (orientation:portrait) {
  .img-logo__tree_hidden {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

And it is work.